# Using generic types in a static context

Tags: java, generics, static

```
public static BTNode<E> treeCopy(BTNode<E> source)
{
     if(source == null)
         return null;
     else
     {
         BTNode left = BTNode.treeCopy(source.left);
         BTNode right = BTNode.treeCopy(source.right);
         return new BTNode(source.data, left, right);
     }

}
```

My questions is why can't I use the generic Type E in a static context? I tried search for several answers couldn't find any that make snese.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static method in a generic class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to declare the generic type in the method signature. Since this is a static method - it cannot grab generic information from anywhere else. So it needs to be declared right here:

```
public static <E> BTNode<E> treeCopy(BTNode<E> source)
{
     if(source == null)
         return null;
     else
     {
         BTNode<E> left = BTNode.treeCopy(source.left);
         BTNode<E> right = BTNode.treeCopy(source.right);
         return new BTNode(source.data, left, right);
     }
}
```

Comment: Its always good if you give little explanation of why it is required.

Answer (score 14):

`E` can mean anything. To use `E` (as a generic) you need to create an instance of an object. You cannot do this if you have a static method because the generic type-parameters are only in scope for an instance of the class (which includes its instance methods and instance fields).

Static members and fields belong to every instance of the class. So if you had an instance of `BTNode<String>` and another instance of `BTNode<Integer>`, what exactly should the static `treeCopy` be using? `String` or `Integer`?

There is a workaroud; you have to tell the static method what `E` means. So you will have to define it like this:

```
public static <E> BTNode<E> treeCopy(BTNode<E> source)
```

It would also help to take a second look at your design and see if this is actually what you want.