# How to call static method from a generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class containing a static create method.

```
public class TestClass {

 public static <E> TestClass<E> create() {
    return new TestClass<E>();
  }

}
```

when I use `TestClass.create()` , it can be compiled. But when I use `TestClass<String>.create()`, it failed to compile, how to specify the generic?

Comment: This [link][1] might help you...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class

Comment: Your example isn't a generic class, it is a generic method.

Comment: Shouldn't the class declaration be `public class TestClass<E>` or `public class Something`? I'm irritated that the class body uses TestClass as a generic when the declaration is concrete!?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about specifying the type explicitly in case type inference fails, you can use `TestClass.<String>create()` (notice how the type is after the `.` as opposed to before).

Comment: Thanks. why the syntax like this, very counter-intuitive?

Comment: I don't think anyone expect those who designed generics would be able to answer that but I think it's to differentiate between creation of a generic class and supplying additional type parameters to generic method of a non-generic class.

Comment: Th syntax is not counter-intuitive to me. The generic parameter is part of the method signature and not the class signature. Therefor is should come after the dot. Note that in most cases the Generic type ca be inferred and this explicit type information is redundant, just like  `List<String> strings = Collections.emptyList();`

Comment: @M Platvoet: It's counter-intuitive because the type parameter comes after the dot and not the method name.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, that's pretty... unintuitive.

A sidenote from Josh Bloch's presentation of his Effective Java, 2nd Edition about the issue: *"God kills a kitten every time you specify an explicit type parameter"*. I would like to avoid constructs like this but sometimes it cannot be evaded.

The trick is to specify the generic parameter after the `.` character: `TestClass.<String>create()`.

Comment: is it same as TestClass<String> some = TestClass.create()?

Answer (score 1):

The generic type can be specified in the class declaration:

```
public class TestClass<E> {

    public static <E> TestClass<E> create() {
        return new TestClass<E>();
    }
}

// Elsewhere in the code
TestClass<String> testClass = TestClass.create();
```

Comment: you mean I don't need to specify type in the create method?

Comment: No he means it can be inferred by the compiler as happens in this example.