# Design for NIL node in generic class

Tags: java

I am creating a specialist tree collection and would like to have `NIL` nodes instead of `null` references. As a contrived example:

```
public interface Value<V> {
    boolean hasValue(V value);
}

public class Node<V> implements Value<V> {
    private static final Value<V> NIL = new Value() {
        public boolean hasValue(V value) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Value<V> next = NIL;
    private V value;

    public boolean hasValue(V value) {
        return this.value.equals(value) || next.hasValue(value);
    }
}
```

I realise this code is illegal because the static member `NIL` is using the generic type `V`. There is a good explanation of why in [java static class Singleton with generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976164/java-static-class-singleton-with-generic/) However that highlights that there needs to be a single instance irrespective of type. That will work fine in my case: the behaviour of `NIL` is identical.

There are some simple workarounds in this case but in the use case I'm working on there are several variants of `NIL` each of which overrides behaviour in the interface.

I could make `NIL` a separate class and create a new instance rather than using a constant but I am dealing with a very large collection and don't want the overhead of many objects that don't actually hold any state.

Is there an elegant way to have a single constant object while retaining the ability to override methods which use the generic type? If not, is there an alternate design that achieves the same outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You could put an unsafe upcast to a generic getter function. See the source of java.util.Collections EMPTY_LIST vs. emptyList() for an example.