# Cannot call instance method in a Comparator generic class

Tags: java, generics, comparator, comparable

My question is close to this one ([Static method in a generic class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class)) but a bit different I think?

Say I have a `Employee` class with an instance method `getSalary()`

```
public class Employee {
    protected long employeeId;
    protected int salary;

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
}
```

And also a Comparator generic class `MyComparator`

```
public class MyComparator<Employee> implements Comparator<Employee> {
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        return emp1.getSalary() - emp2.getSalary();
    }
}
```

Now I have a warning of `MyComparator<Employee>` and error of calling the `getSalary()` instance method.

I think I am missing something here but not exact understand what is going on? What is the best way to declare a generic comparator over `Employee` class? The best practice? Or implementing a `Comparable` of `Employee` in below code is suggested?

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    protected long employeeId;
    protected int salary;

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee e) {
        return this.salary - e.salary;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions welcome and appreciated!

Comment: "Now I have a warning of MyComparator<Employee> and error of calling the getSalary() instance method." What warning?  What error?  This looks fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring a type parameter `Employee` in your `Comparator` class. That class declaration is same as:

```
public class MyComparator<T> implements Comparator<T>
```

Get the issue? You should change that class to:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        return emp1.getSalary() - emp2.getSalary();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `MyComparator<Employee>` is the same as writing `MyComparator<E extends Object>`

What I expect you meant to write was

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        return emp1.getSalary() - emp2.getSalary();
    }
}
```

In this case `Employee` is a class instead of a parameterized type.