# Generic static factory

Tags: java, generics

I am getting a compilation error. I want my static method here to return a factory that creates and return `Event<T>` object. How can I fix this?

```
import com.lmax.disruptor.EventFactory;

public final class Event<T> {

    private T event;

    public T getEvent() {

        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(final T event) {

        this.event = event;
    }

    public final static EventFactory<Event<T>> EVENT_FACTORY = new EventFactory<Event<T>>() {

        public Event<T> newInstance() {

            return new Event<T>();
        }


     };

}
```

Comment: I don't see a static method...

Comment: So...what's an `EventFactory`?  It looks like you're trying to use one before it's defined...

Comment: Posting the compilation error might also help

Comment: Maybe, the issue is that generic types cannot be bound to static objects. `Event<T>` does not exist for a static member of `Event`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static method in a generic class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class) -- slightly different use case but same problem and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic parameters of a class do not apply to static members.

The obvious solution is to use a method rather than a variable.

```
public static <U> EventFactory<Event<U>> factory() {
    return new EventFactory<Event<U>>() {
        public Event<U> newInstance() {
            return new Event<U>();
        }
    };
}
```

The syntax is more concise in the current version of Java.

It is possible to use a the same instance of `EventFactory` stored in a static field, but that requires an unsafe cast.

Comment: Oh! You are too fast.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
public final class Event<T> {
    ...
    public final static EventFactory<Event<T>> EVENT_FACTORY = ...
}
```

You cannot do this. `T` is a type that is associated with a specific instance of an `Event<T>`, and you cannot use it in a static context.

It's hard to give you good alternate options without knowing more about what exactly you are trying to do, as this is sort of an odd-looking factory implementation. I suppose you could do something like (put it in a method instead):

```
public final class Event<T> {
    ...
    public static <U> EventFactory<Event<U>> createEventFactory () { 
        return new EventFactory<Event<U>>() {
            public Event<U> newInstance() {
                return new Event<U>();
            }
        };
    };
}
```

And invoke it like:

```
EventFactory<Event<Integer>> factory = Event.<Integer>createEventFactory();
```

Or, if you don't want to be explicit (you don't really need to be, here):

```
EventFactory<Event<Integer>> factory = Event.createEventFactory();
```

Why don't you get rid of the whole static member of `Event` thing and either keep the factories separate, e.g.:

```
public final class GenericEventFactory<T> extends EventFactory<Event<T>> {
    @Override public Event<T> newInstance() {
        return new Event<T>();
    }
}
```

And use, e.g., `new GenericEventFactory<Integer>()` where appropriate?

Comment: `Event.createEventFactory()` without the `<Integer>` should work.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline True. I wanted to illustrate, but I added that in.