# Why is it that a generic type can be defined for a static method only?

Tags: java, generics

Book, Introduction to Java Programming, says, "A generic type can be defined for a static method."
**Why instance methods can't be generic?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static method in a generic class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class)

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister The possible duplicate you suggested doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Agreed - it's a completely different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instance methods **can** be generic. The following code compiles with Java 5 and later. As you can see, I have defined a generic instance method and a generic static method in the same way.

```
package com.company;

public class Generics {
    public <T> T returnAGenericType(T returnThisOne) {
        return returnThisOne;
    }

    public static <T> T returnAGenericTypeStatic(T returnThisOne) {
        return returnThisOne;
    }
}
```

`ArrayList::toArray`, `ArrayList::get` and `ArrayList::set` are all examples of instance methods with generic type parameters.

Comment: Oh, the book uses java 7. Thanks!

Comment: The same is true of java 7. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would they make a generic type definable for a static method only (in java 7).

Comment: I was only saying that I had only tried it in Java 8. I have now tried it in Java 5, 6, 7, and 8 and it all works the same. The is absolutely no reason in any version of Java to have generic types definable for static methods only.

Comment: according to the book, however, **"A generic type can be defined for a static method."**

Comment: Indeed it can. That is not the same as saying you can't do it for instance methods.