# How to parametrize object by the same type as the given object?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `ListCreator<T>` and a static method `collectFrom()` which fabricates an instance of this class. `collectFrom()` has a parameter `List l` and I would like to parametrize returned instance of the `ListCreator` with the same type as the specified `List` is.

Ideally I would like something like that:

```
public static ListCreator<T> collectFrom(List<T> l) {
    return new ListCreator<T>(l);
}
```

but this is impossible so I am stuck with this:

```
public class ListCreator<T> { 

    List<T> l;

    public ListCreator(List<T> l) {
        this.l = l;
    }

    public static ListCreator collectFrom(List l) {
        return new ListCreator(l);
    }
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Genericize your method by introducing the type parameter in its definition:

```
public static <T> ListCreator<T> collectFrom(List<T> l) {
    return new ListCreator<T>(l);
}
```

In fact, the type parameter declared in `class ListCreator<T> {` has no meaning for this method since it is `static` (see [Static method in a generic class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class)).

Comment: It has a meaning for the constructor and the member variable.