# Java Generics - How to write static methods with type arguments?

Tags: java, generics

Coming from a C++ background, I was hoping to write few util static methods which could be used throughout my application without necessarily going via object creation. And I was hoping to use the equivalence of function templates in Java Generics. At this point, I want to clarify that I am learning Java generics.

But on trying that, I could see that the compiler would not allow me to do so. And I could see some [very good discussion as well here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class). But then I played around with the warning message a little bit to write an inner static class with similar touch, and as per my intuition it worked there. Now obviously, it is clumsy to access inner classes which I have presented below. I wonder why this has been designed this way in Java and good will this inner class offer with generics to outside classes.

```
public class ReflectionBasics<X, Y> {

    public static void findMax (X xData, Y yData ){
       // compiler error - cannot reference static type to non-static type X 
    }

    public void findMin(X xData, Y yData){
        // this is fine
    }

    static final class InnerClass<E> {
        public void findMin(E data){
            // this will work
        }
    }
}
```

Clumsy Accessor:

```
class AccessorClass{
    AccessorClass(){
        ReflectionBasics.InnerClass<Integer> myData = new ReflectionBasics.InnerClass<Integer>();
        myData.findMin(400);

    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html Java has generic methods. Also note that Java generics are not templates and can not do many things that C++ templates can do. (On the other hand, they can do a few things that C++ templates *can't* do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put type parameters on a method, you just stick them before the return type (which you probably didn't want to be `void`):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T findMax(T a, T b) {
    ...
}
```

In most cases, you can skip the type parameters at the call site, and they'll be inferred for you:

```
Integer max = WhateverClass.findMax(integerA, integerB);
```

Comment: The correct declaration is `public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void findMax(T a, T b) {`

Comment: @fRoStBiT: Bah, that's what I get for trying to reproduce the awkward syntax from memory. I guess it makes sense to introduce the type parameter before the return type, which could depend on that parameter.

Comment: @fRoStBiT  - I thank you for responding on a postive note to my query. I also thank whoever has down voted this question, although I really pity his thought process. This question was not meant for him anyway. I am sure many new java programmers like me will have such genuine question. I can make it that many people did not know the answer. The first person to respond was someone who had 58.9K rep and he was 26th visitor.