# Extending Generic Interface for generic validation

Tags: java, generics

I have been playing with the validation pattern from [this](https://gtrefs.github.io/code/combinator-pattern/) blog post. Everything works out as expected but I am unable to add generics. Namely,

```
public interface Validator extends Function<User, ValidationResult> {
    static Validator validate(Predicate<User> tester, String error) {
        return user -> 
            tester.test(user) ? ValidationResult.valid() : 
                    ValidationResult.invalid(error);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to make the `Validator` interface generic

```
public interface Validator<T> extends Function<T, ValidationResult> {
    static Validator validate(Predicate<T> tester, String error) {
        return subject ->
                tester.test(subject) ? ValidationResult.valid() :
                        ValidationResult.invalid(error);
    }
}
```

I get a compilation error:

> Validatior.this cannot be referenced from the static context.

[image]

I can't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class) answer your question?

Comment: What exactly is your use case? It's not clear from your code. For example, your _`Validator.validate()`_ returns a _`Validator`_. So what do you intend for callers of that method to do with that _`Validator`_ they get back? Just looking at the code as it is now, the only thing they *can* do is call _`Validator.validate()`_...to get another _`Validator`_????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> „…*I can't understand why. What am I doing wrong?*…“

What you're doing wrong is referring to the type parameter in a  *static* context. [*The JLS says that's not allowed*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2-320)…

> ***It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic class C in any of the following***:
>
> - *the declaration of a static member of C* ([*§8.3.1.1*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1), [*§8.4.3.2*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2), [*§8.5.1*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1)).
> - *the declaration of a static member of any type declaration nested within C*.
> - *a static initializer of C* ([*§8.7*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)), *or*
> - *a static initializer of any class declaration nested within C*.

One way to make your code compile is to change it to this…

```
public interface Validator<T> extends Function<T, ValidationResult> {
    
    default Validator validate(Predicate<T> tester, String error) {
        return user -> 
            tester.test((T)user) ? ValidationResult.valid() : 
                    ValidationResult.invalid(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first answer assumes you want nothing more than for the original code you posted to compile; with the fewest changes made to it. So that answer addresses ***only*** that assumption.

This is a different answer because it makes a different assumption; and requires more than one code change.

***Assumption***: *You absolutely ***must*** have a static method?*

You could get that with the following refactors:

- Introduce a *`Validatible`* interface…

  ```
    public interface Validatible{ 

        boolean isValid();

    }
  ```
- Make *`User`* a *`Validatiable`*…

  ```
    public class User implements Validatible{
        ...

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(){
            ...
        }
        ... 
    }
  ```
- Simplify *`Validator`*…

  ```
    public interface Validator {

        ValidationResult validate(Validatible input);
    }
  ```
- Move your ***must-have*** *`static`* method to a utility/helper class…

  ```
    public class DeduperAnswer {

        static Validator validate(Predicate<Validatible> tester, String error) {
            return user -> 
                tester.test(user) ? ValidationResult.valid() : 
                        ValidationResult.invalid(error);
        }
        ...
    }
  ```

You could then call *`DeduperAnswer.validate()`* [*like I do in this demo*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_304530)…

```
    Validator butWhatThen = DeduperAnswer.validate((user) -> { return user.isValid(); }, "not valid");
```

But like I asked in the comments, after you get back that *`Validator`* from the *`static`* method call, what do you intend to do with it then?

I've made the assumptions I've made because it's not 100% clear what your exact use case is. It would be super helpful if you would share that.

Comment: It's tricky to explain but here is what I am doing: I tried to code the example of User validator from this article: https://gtrefs.github.io/code/combinator-pattern/ It worked as expected. In my project I need to validate many types of objects: `User`, `Product`, `OrderForm`, etc. .. so I wanted to add generic instead of `User` so I can reuse this construct validating other objects. So I needed to change `User` to `<T>`

Comment: „*...In my project I need to validate many types of objects...so I can reuse this construct validating other objects...*“ — It is true, @AstroSharp, that generics is one way to get polymorphism. But it's not the only way. It's certainly not the simplest way. Some people even [*think that it's the worst way*](https://old.reddit.com/r/java/comments/i08y90/shops_on_java_18_that_use_it_like_java_16/fzre22j/). The _`Validatible`_ interface in this answer provides the subtype polymorphism you're describing. I'm curious to learn what your thoughts are on that approach?